# how to add an array in source while working on autocomplete in yii 1

Tags: php, yii

I want to print an array into source. 
Here is my code.

Controller:

```
public function actionAutocomplete()
{       
        $user= new User;
        $reg=User::model()->autocomplete();

        $this->render('autocomplete',array(
            'model'=>$user, 'auto'=>$reg,
        )); 
}
```

Model:

```
    public function autocomplete()
    {
        $rr = User::model()->findAll(array("select"=>"regname","order"=>"regname DESC"));
        return $rr;
    }
```

View:

```
<H3>ZII WIDGETS</H3>
<H5>Autocomplete Text Box</H5>
<?php
//print_r ($auto);
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete',array(
    'name'=>'city',
    'source'=>$auto,
    // additional javascript options for the autocomplete plugin
    'options'=>array(
        'minLength'=>'2',
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'style'=>'height:20px;',
    ),
));

?>
```

Here i want to add `$auto` array into source in view, i have retrive column data and and return successfully. Now what is the next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi You are doing all good but one problem is that your are passing whole `User Model` `Object` as a `Source` to `juiwidget`.

Just change this `function` in your model

```
    public function autocomplete()
    {
        $rr = User::model()->findAll(array("select"=>"regname","order"=>"regname DESC"));
$new = array();
    foreach($rr as $data){
        $new[] = $data->regname;

    }
return $new;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**View :**

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
    'name'=>'city',
    'value'=>'test21',
    'source'=>$this->createUrl('<controllerName>/autocomplete'),
    // additional javascript options for the autocomplete plugin
    'options'=>array(
        'minLength'=>'2',
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'style'=>'height:20px;',
    ),
));
```

**Controller :**

```
public function actionAutocomplete()
{       
        $user= new User;
        $reg=User::model()->autocomplete();

        echo CJSON::encode(CHtml::listData($reg,'key_fieldname', 'value_fieldname'));
        exit; 
}
```

Comment: Is any error?
Can you please check console?
Or try to return value in json format

Comment: when i print the array it shows the data, and when  i add a simple this array('ac1','ac2') in source then its working fine.... i am new in yii , now what to do ? no error here

Comment: i just update code of controller. can you please check it out?

Comment: print_r(CHtml::listData($reg,'regname', 'regname') );  should id do like that??? i need regname from the table is user it print this    Array ( [traveltoexplore] => traveltoexplore [admin1] => admin1 )

Comment: yes, If you want to store regname, then its fine.
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/by-example-chtml/

Comment: just improve answer